# Compare PermissionRequest object for Camera and Microphone in Xamarin.Android

Tags: webview, xamarin.android, webkit, android-permissions

I have Xamarin.Android app which has a `webview` and asks permissions for camera and microphone. In my `public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request)`, I want to check what is the permission requesting and show the relavant alert. But I don't know how to check whether its Camera permission or microphone. How can I check it? 
Thanks!

Comment: Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code , **PermissionRequest**  contains the request which the webview want to apply.

```
public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request)
{
   base.OnPermissionRequest(request);

   var resources = request.GetResources();

   foreach ( var permission in resources)
   {
     if(permission == PermissionRequest.ResourceVideoCapture)
     {
        // apply camera permission
     }

     if(permission==PermissionRequest.ResourceAudioCapture)
     {
       // apply microphone permission
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: There is another problem,, Microphone permission not enabling automatically. I have to manually open app settings and enable microphone for my app